# Problemas con el metodo with() en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy realizando la siguiente query.

```
$Products = Product::with('productFiles')->where("name", "like", "%{$request->value}%")->limit(10)->get();
```

Esta query me llama todos los productos y un array llamado "productFiles" CON DATOS. Pero si le agrego un select como el siguiente, el array "productFiles" se muestra vacio.

```
$Products = Product::select('name', 'slug')->with('productFiles')->where("name", "like", "%{$request->value}%")->limit(10)->get();
```

Debo aclarar que productFiles es un metodo del modelo Product, está declarado así.

```
public function productFiles(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductFile::class);
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un callback, donde envías la query y le añades el whereRaw de productFile y el addSelect con  los nombres de las columnas  de la tabla relación que necesitas.
Cuando lo obtienes con ->get() envías las columnas de la tabla producut

```
$Products = Product::with(['productFiles' => function($q){
  $q->addSelect(['name'])
  ->whereRaw('"name", "like", "%{$request->value}%""')
  ->limit(10);
}])->get(['name', 'slug']);
```

Comment: Excelente Juan2Ramos